# NSDateComponents (via MTDates) is returning a strange number for hour (mt_hourOfDay)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I've looked at the related questions with answers, their solutions have not worked. I'm really confused by the output I'm receiving from NSDateComponents and NSDateFormatter (and MTDates for ease of use but I've tried bypassing that to get different results to no avail).

Here is a link of the relevant section of the UI (from simulator): http://grab.by/rFbQ

As well as logs relevant to the issue:

```
2013-10-31 23:58:03.407 Application[22530:70b] Date 2013-11-01 04:58:03 +0000
2013-10-31 23:58:03.408 Application[22530:70b] Formatted Date Oct 31, 2013, 11:58:03 PM
2013-10-31 23:58:03.408 Application[22530:70b] Hours 17
2013-10-31 23:58:03.408 Application[22530:70b] Minutes 9
```

Code used to get the numbers:

```
[NSDate mt_setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *current = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:current];

NSUInteger hours = comp.hour;
NSUInteger minutes = ceil([current mt_minuteOfHour] / 6);

NSLog(@"Date %@", current);
NSLog(@"Formatted Date %@", [formatter stringFromDate:current]);
NSLog(@"Hours %lx", hours);
NSLog(@"Minutes %lx", minutes);

self.dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:current];
self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lx.%lx", hours, minutes];
```

I don't know if you could tell from the output above but the formatted date (for the correct timezone) shows the hour as "11" ("11:58:03") which baffles me when, even setting the timezone for the `NSCalendar` and `NSDateFormatter` to the same `NSTimeZone` (`localTimeZone`) I get "17" as the current hour.

I should also mention that I'm using [MTDates](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates) to augment date actions but was encountering this issue before I included this library (hoping it's inclusion might somehow make these results more sane). That being said I've also tried replacing the portion where I fetch my own components with:

```
NSUInteger hours = [current mt_hourOfDay];
```

This, unfortunately, returns "17" as well. I would expect it to return "23" but would be happy with and "11" and could then figure out converting it to a 24 scale.

Comment: The `%x` format specifier is for hex. Use `%d` for decimal (Base 10). 23 decimal is 17 hex.

Comment: @maddy Wow... do I feel like an idiot now or what. My unfamiliarity with formatting components and the lack of specification in the documentation (`NSUInteger %lu or %lx` from the docs) led me around blindly. The thought never occurred to me. If you don't mind writing that in an answer (I realize it's not much) I'll give you the accept. It is the solution to my problem.

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the format specifier `%lx` which will format the numbers as hex values. You want `%ld` to get decimal (base 10).

See the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for some basic format specifiers.

See the [IEEE spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for a complete list of the `printf` style format specifiers. Objective-C uses this spec with the addition of `%@` for objects.

Comment: I realized after I made my initial comment that they included in the docs that `%x` and `%X` format in hex which I completely overlooked, and should have applied to `%lx` thanks for pointing that out.